# Phone web page is first opened images placeholder

Tags: javascript, php, html, placeholder

I made a phone page, just open the page because the images is not loaded completely instantly lead contents all stacked together, waiting for images to load after the page was completely normal.
So I think to make images width, height attributes, but different phone size, the width of each images is change, resulting in a height to be recalculated, will slow in the inside pages through javascript computing, the problem is not resolved.
Is there a way in PHP controller which will calculate the width of the page? Then directly assigned to the page?

Or is there other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: http://www.foream.cn/specialcolumn/index/type/0/id/54.html  You can use the phone to open this page, the first time you open the page because the images is not set height result page squeezed together.

Comment: So I have to know at the beginning of the page load image width and height, and then set the <img src = '{src}' height = '{height}' width = '{width}' />, but I can no longer page load First you get the images width and height, how can I do?